# correct validate inputs

Tags: plugins, sql

How correct validate data from user to save in database from inputs?

I use this for textfields:

```
        $name = trim(sanitize_text_field($_POST['name']));
```

But if i add special signs like "&*({} Something like this ^&({}<>", then they add without a problem.

I need add only "Something like this" without special signs.

Comment: For reference, WordPress provides some guidance for validating and sanitizing user input: https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `$name = trim( sanitize_user( $_POST['name'], true ) );`

Be sure that the function does what you want! Read [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_user)

Comment: Work, thanks. I have question about secure data. How check if variable is INT?

Comment: There are some... like "is_int" to verify if it's exact an int. But if you want to see if a string can be converted to int, the "is_numeric" is a function that can check that. If you want to parse a string to int/float you can use "intval" or "floatval". And be sure that the expected int is a valid one. If you expect an int that is a positive number, then be sure is it, or else you could have some bugs.

Comment: Be careful if you use "is_numeric", as will validate hex strings as integers, and mysql will see them as strings, example [here](https://www.netsparker.com/blog/web-security/sql-injection-cheat-sheet/#UsingIntegers)